# Take published Date with youtube api v3

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api

I take publishedAt date but ı need to change date type.
Now,2017-01-19T14:02:39.000Z
but I want this type, 19-01-2017,
my codes,

```html
$.get(
 "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems",{
  part : 'snippet',
  maxResults : 20,
  playlistId : pid,
  key : 'AIzaSyBZvGyNmLVPDLPcz_clh8tGxl0_1DRNFFE'},
  function(data) {
   var output;
   $.each(data.items, function(i,item) {
    console.log(item);
    videoTitle = item.snippet.title;
    videoId = item.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
    videoDate = item.snippet.publishedAt;
    videoGorsel = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
    height = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.height;
    width = item.snippet.thumbnails.default.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have parsed the response and obtained the date value 2017-01-19T14:02:39.000Z, here's how to do it.
Using the [Date methods from W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp):

```
var isODate = new Date("2017-01-19T14:02:39.000Z");

var shortDate = new Date(isODate);
var day = shortDate.getDate();
var month = shortDate.getMonth() + 1;
var year = shortDate.getFullYear();

var stringdate = day+"-"+month+"-"+year;
console.log(stringdate);
```

**OUTPUT**: `19-1-2017`